# Android Terminal does not recognise firebase command

Tags: firebase, android-studio, terminal

I have this weird situation where I am not able to run `firebase` commands from android studio. I can run such commands in terminal but not in the terminal inside android studio.

As an example if I run `firebase login` in terminal, I can login but if run it in android studio I get this error: `zsh: command not found: firebase`.

See below an image to prove this case.

[image]

I tried to run the following command and got the following in terminal

```
MyMac:my_folder myuser$ which firebase
/Users/myuser/.nvm/versions/node/v17.0.1/bin/firebase
MyMac:my_folder myuser$ readlink $(which firebase)
../lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/bin/firebase.js
```

If I do the same in Android I get nothing. I suspect it is a matter of Android studio not finding the right path to the firebase files?

Any help?

I am on a macOS Ventura and using Android Studio Electric Eel

Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 1):

How did you install firebase tools (locally or globally)?

if you have globally installed firebase-cli,
I suggest you to look into environment `PATH` variables for both nodejs and firebase tools.

if you have installed locally as a dependancy,
[here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#install-cli-mac-linux) is a installation guide to install firebase-cli on macOS.

Eitherway, I suggest you to Invalidate cache and restart your Android studio before running the terminal again.